# Selecting row which column meeting condition in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen3

```
    one two three four
 [1,]   1   6    11   16
 [2,]   2   7    12   17
 [3,]   3   8    11   18
 [4,]   4   9    11   19
 [5,]   5  10    15   20
```

I want to extract the submatrix whose rows have column three = 11. That is:

```
      one two three four
 [1,]   1   6    11   16
 [3,]   3   8    11   18
 [4,]   4   9    11   19
```

How to do this in Eigen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eigen3 select rows out based on column conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58350524/eigen3-select-rows-out-based-on-column-conditions)

Answer (score 1):

An `Eigen::Array` of booleans containing information on whether a row of the matrix meets the criterion can be defined with

```
enum cols {one, two, three, four};
auto is_selected = (mat.col(three).array() == 11);
```

The array `is_selected`, possibly after casting it into a vector of integers, can then be used to construct a new matrix consisting of the selected rows of the original one, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58353969/4770166).