# Eigen3 select rows out based on column conditions

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I have a matrix in eigen which is 2 dimensions, such as:

```
122 443 544 456 0.9
324 435 5465 645 0.8
32 434 545 546 0.778
435 546 6565 656 0.6878
546 6565 656 3453 54 0.7788
5456 546 545 6565 3434 0.244
435 5456 656 656 6565 0.445
.....
```

I want select all rows (or get it's row index out) when the last column value bigger than 0.3.

I know I can do this by iteration all rows and judge the last element, but I have maybe 10000 rows, to do this, iteration will be very slow.

Does there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The selection of the relevant rows can be done in a single line, by storing the result of the comparison of all the elements in the last column into a boolean array, which can be cast into a VectorXi.

```
VectorXi is_selected = (mat.col(last_col).array() > 0.3).cast<int>();
```

This information can then be used to prepare a new matrix which contains only the selected rows. An entire code using this method is shown below.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>    
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {
  const int nr = 10;
  const int nc = 5;
  MatrixXd mat = MatrixXd::Random(nr,nc);
  std::cout << "original:\n" << mat << std::endl;
  int last_col = mat.cols() - 1;

  VectorXi is_selected = (mat.col(last_col).array() > 0.3).cast<int>();

  MatrixXd mat_sel(is_selected.sum(), mat.cols());
  int rownew = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows(); ++i) {
    if (is_selected[i]) {       
       mat_sel.row(rownew) = mat.row(i);
       rownew++;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "selected:\n" << mat_sel << std::endl;
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/f0_fC0

**Edit: Using new feature (Eigen 3.4 or 3.3.90 development branch)**

The development branch of Eigen provides a new overload of the MatrixX constructor that allows for the direct subsetting of a given matrix.

```
MatrixXd mat_sel = mat(keep_rows, keep_cols);
```

The columns and rows that should be kept are stored in an `Eigen::VectorXi` or in a `std::vector<int>`:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {
  MatrixXd mat = MatrixXd::Random(10,5);
  std::cout << "original:\n" << mat << std::endl;
  std::vector<int> keep_rows;  
  for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows(); ++i) {
    if (mat(i,mat.cols() - 1) > 0.3) {
       keep_rows.push_back(i);
     }     
  }
  VectorXi keep_cols = VectorXi::LinSpaced(mat.cols(), 0, mat.cols());
  MatrixXd mat_sel = mat(keep_rows, keep_cols);          
  std::cout << "selected:\n" << mat_sel << std::endl; 
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Ag7g7f

Comment: So much thanks for your answer sir! It seems perfectly worked still got one last question: what if I have 10000 rows? To iteration them is the fastest way to do this? Does there any original way to do this? I checked the Eigen doc, it says from 3.39 on, there would have a way `a(Eigen::all, indcies)` to do this, but default eigen is 3.35 does not have a `Eigen::all`

Comment: I have test on 10000 examples, it cost about 2 ms to get selected matrix. which is slightly slow.

Comment: Syntactic sugar aside, I assume that the selection of the rows will hardly be possible in a way that is much faster than the one-liner that I mentioned. One could consider selecting the rows on the fly, with `if(mat(i,last_col) > 0.3)` instead of `if(is_selected[i])`, i.e., without prior storage of the is_selected vector. That's essentially what @ignacio suggested. But then we don’t know at the beginning of the loop how many rows will be chosen, and since there is no `row_push_back()` method, additional operations will be needed at the end in order to adjust the size of the matrix `mat_sel`.

Comment: @NicholasJela Please have a look at the edit. A new feature of Eigen allows to construct the matrix `mat_sel` directly as a subset of `mat`. I assume that this is much faster than the loop shown in the first part.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the column instead of the row and compare last column to a vector [n x 1] of 0.3

Comment: But how to do this? Any snippets?