# How to get the rows based on condition in eigen?

Tags: c++, c++17, eigen

I need to get the certain rows, when a element is a vector is one.

For an example:

```
std::vector<bool>index{};   //contains 6000 numbers of elements 0 and 1
```

Now I have a matrix mat of shape (6000,4)

How can I get the rows in a matrix mat, when the corresponding element is 1 in vector index.

```
mat = mat[index];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question clearly, you may find good answer from this good reply:

[Eigen3 select rows out based on column conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58350524/eigen3-select-rows-out-based-on-column-conditions)

Using new feature (Eigen 3.4 or 3.3.90 development branch) and take the core code from the previous link:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {
MatrixXd mat = MatrixXd::Random(10,5);
std::cout << "original:\n" << mat << std::endl;
std::vector<int> keep_rows;  
for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows(); ++i) {
    if (mat(i,mat.cols() - 1) > 0.3) {
       keep_rows.push_back(i);
    }     
 }
VectorXi keep_cols = VectorXi::LinSpaced(mat.cols(), 0,mat.cols());
MatrixXd mat_sel = mat(keep_rows, keep_cols);          
std::cout << "selected:\n" << mat_sel << std::endl; 
}
```

It uses the similar style of the Matlab:

```
MatrixXd mat_sel = mat(keep_rows, keep_cols);
```

But the columns and rows that should be kept are stored in an

```
Eigen::VectorXi
```

or in a

```
std::vector<int>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29410489)

Comment: Add the core code based on the reference link.